# Extension recommendation for "Zalando"-like filter functionality in layered navigation

Tags: extensions, layered-navigation, filter

I'm looking for an extension that implements the filter in the layered navigation much like popular german retailer Zalando:

https://www.zalando.de/damenbekleidung-shirts/ (You can see the filter right below the "Shirts & Tops" title)

The main requirements are:

- Toggle-able filter display
- Multi-value selection using checkboxes, without refreshing the page after each selection

Does anybody have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Mana Dev has a paid extension that does this

http://www.manadev.com/horizontal-layered-navigation-positioning

Another alternative is Amasty
https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html